# How to set the row as ReadOnly - DevExpress VCL TcxRTTIInspector

Tags: delphi, devexpress, row, readonly, vcl

We are using Delphi 10 with DevExpress V19.2.4.

`cxMyRTTIInspector1.InspectedObject := myObject;`

We have 10 rows, I found the first row is `ReadOnly` and the rest 9 rows are editable (bold), (I could not figure that out why was that, although we have source code but...)

Is there a way I can set a row as readonly?
Thanks

Comment: Maybe this depends on the type of the property shown in the rows? What does the class declaration of `myObject` look like?

Answer (score 1):

You can force a property to be not editable from the `TcxRTTIInspector` in this way:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, cxGraphics, cxControls,
  cxLookAndFeels, cxLookAndFeelPainters, cxStyles, dxScrollbarAnnotations,
  cxEdit, cxInplaceContainer, cxVGrid, cxOI;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    cxRTTIInspector1: TcxRTTIInspector;
    procedure cxRTTIInspector1ItemChanged(Sender: TObject;
      AOldRow: TcxCustomRow; AOldCellIndex: Integer);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FForcedReadOnlyProperty : string;
    { Private declarations }
  public
    function IsForcedReadOnlyProperty(const APropertyName : string) : boolean;
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

function TForm1.IsForcedReadOnlyProperty(const APropertyName : string) : boolean;
begin
  Result := FForcedReadOnlyProperty = APropertyName;
end;

procedure TForm1.cxRTTIInspector1ItemChanged(Sender: TObject;
  AOldRow: TcxCustomRow; AOldCellIndex: Integer);
begin
  TcxRTTIInspector(Sender).OptionsData.Editing := (
    Assigned(TcxRTTIInspector(Sender).FocusedRow) and
    (not IsForcedReadOnlyProperty(TcxPropertyRow(TcxRTTIInspector(Sender).FocusedRow).Properties.Caption))
  );
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FForcedReadOnlyProperty := 'Caption';
  cxRTTIInspector1.InspectedObject := Self;
end;

end.
```

If you want to highlight these properties you can do that by using the `Styles.OnGetContentStyle` and/or `Styles.OnGetHeaderStyle` event handlers

Comment: @RickyNelson: Great! if it solved the problem, please [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/386306)